# Adding multiple X509VerificationFlags in C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate

I'm struggling with some X509Certificate stuff for making calls to a HTTPS webservice. Where I'm building this the root CA is not trusted, but it is valid to me personally for what program I'm working on. So I was looking into using the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in C# to get this working as found on another stackoverflow question.

I'm wondering is there a way to add multiple [X509VerificationFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509verificationflags?view=netframework-4.7.2) in order for the certificate to pass. I'm just nervous overriding the .NET implementation.

```
Boolean ServerCertificateValidationCallback(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    X509Certificate2 UATrootCA = new X509Certificate2("MyInvalidRootCAButIWantToTrustItAnyway.cer");
    // remove this line if commercial CAs are not allowed to issue certificate for your service.
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.None)) > 0) { return true; }

    if (
        (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)) > 0 ||
        (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)) > 0
    ) { return false; }
    // get last chain element that should contain root CA certificate    
    //X509Certificate2 projectedRootCert = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate;
    //if (projectedRootCert.Thumbprint == UATrootCA.Thumbprint)
    //{
    //    return true;  // I could return true here if I really wanted to and it would work fine, but I feel like there might be a better way...
    //}
    // execute certificate chaining engine and ignore only "UntrustedRoot" error
    X509Chain customChain = new X509Chain
    {
        ChainPolicy = {
                    VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority
                }
    };
    customChain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(UATrootCA);
    Boolean retValue = customChain.Build(chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate);
    // RELEASE unmanaged resources behind X509Chain class.
    customChain.Reset();
    return retValue;
}
```

---

### UPDATE 1

Thank you for the comment `bartonjs`. Staring at that comment made me feel silly. Sometimes debugging by confession is the best way to go. In the end I ended up with some slightly different code still checking for the thumbprint.

```
Boolean ServerCertificateValidationCallback(Object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    X509Certificate2 UATrootCA = new X509Certificate2("MyInvalidRootCAButIWantToTrustItAnyway.cer"); 
    if (
        (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch)) > 0 ||
        (sslPolicyErrors & (SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable)) > 0
    ) { return false; }
    // get last chain element that should contain root CA certificate
    // but this may not be the case in partial chains
    X509Certificate2 projectedRootCert = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate;

    X509Chain customChain = new X509Chain();
    Boolean retValue = false;
    // execute certificate chaining engine and ignore only "UntrustedRoot" error if our Thumbprint matches.
    if (projectedRootCert.Thumbprint == UATrootCA.Thumbprint)
    {
        customChain = new X509Chain
        {
            ChainPolicy = { VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority }
            //ChainPolicy = { VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority |
            //                                    X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreRootRevocationUnknown  }
            // As bartonjs commented you can use a bitwise-or to add different VerificationFlags which can be very useful
        };
        retValue = customChain.Build(UATrootCA);
    }
    else
    {
        retValue = customChain.Build(chain.ChainElements[0].Certificate);
    }

    // RELEASE unmanaged resources behind X509Chain class.
    customChain.Reset();
    return retValue;
}
```

Comment: "Can you use multiple flags?" Sure, just bitwise-or them together.  Right now your validator will accept almost any non-expired certificate; the commented out version is actually much better. -- I'm not sure that the question your title asks and the question you actually seem to have are the same.

Comment: Thank you.  If you post a solution on bitwise that would sum up what I was initially looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X509VerificationFlags` is a `[Flags]` enumeration, meaning that the values can be combined with bitwise-or.

e.g. to accept an unknown root authority as well as not care about expiration:

```
chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags =
    X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority |
    X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreTimeNotValid;
```